# ruby functional : best practice?

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

Let's say I want to select elements in an array, using a custom method. I'll use parity for the sake of the argument.

Now generally speaking, is there any good practice/recommendation to choose between using

```
class Integer # Adding method to the Integer class
  def my_fancy_select
    self % 2 == 0
  end
end

puts my_array.select(&:my_fancy_select)
```

and

```
def my_fancy_select(i) # could be a private method
  i % 2 == 0
end

puts my_array.select{|i| my_select(i)}
```

,

```
puts my_array.select{|i| 
  i % 2 == 0 # Directly passing a block
}
```

, or even using Procs ?

Comment: [beware subclassing core classes](http://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes). Also, `my_select` is a terrible name for a method. I hope that is just for the sake of this example.

Comment: It was indeed for the sake of the example ! Well, I guess I could still change it :)

Comment: @aherve - leave it - it's a good example.  My upvote of Justin's comment was for his link - `my_select` is just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid adding to `Integer` unless you feel the method is truly addressing a behaviour  of all Integers. Even then you should beware collisions.

Other than that, there is no inherent reason to choose either the second or third forms over the other, especially in your simple example.

Code blocks and methods offer different approaches to code re-use. Blocks work nicely when the "outside" pattern is repeated, and you just want to vary a few lines inside. Methods work nicely when you need to do the exact same "inner" logic in multiple places.

If your filtering logic is indeed repeated in multiple places, then I would favour making it a method on a mixin, or a class method of a suitable custom class, and calling that method in the block. Which is your second example. Otherwise, the direct one-liner with block is suitable for purpose and I can read it all in place, which offers a slight readability advantage (provided code stays DRY) - which is your third example.

Answer (score 2):

A very elegant way is to create a proc or lambda with an appropriate name:

```
even_numbers = -> x {x.even?}
numbers_that_start_with_three = -> x {x.to_s[0] == '3'}

p [11,22,33,4,5,6].select(&even_numbers) #=> [22, 4, 6]
p [11,22,33,4,5,6].select(&numbers_that_start_with_three) #=> [33]
```

Comment: The "Haha" moment : I think that's exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

The way I look at a problem like this is *"What makes the code easiest to read and understand?"*, since all of your solutions effectively do the same thing.

In my opinion, I prefer this:

```
def my_select(i) # could be a private method
  i % 2 == 0
end
puts my_array.select{|i| my_select(i)}
```

Mostly because it's easiest to read and understand.  I also don't like "monkey-patching" core classes (like `Integer`) unless there is *no* other solution.